# SVN Creating a Maintenance Branch

Tags: svn, version-control

A small section in the svn handbook (Under the heading "Release Branches") summarizes my goal really well but provides no sample code on how to go about it. I would really appreciate it if anyone could provide the step by step svn commands required to create and update the "release branch" that the book talks about.

SVN handbook "Release Branch" section: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html

Essentially, I would like create a branch and service a version of my code (which was delivered to a customer) and keep it separate from the trunk where the most latest and experimental code is. I would also like to be able to have incremented versions of that service/maintenance  branch just like you get on a trunk every time you commit.

Also... does a SVN repo even contain the actual filesystem of your software or does it just contain svn files to track your changes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your "release" branch (just "copy" command from svn or create the branch via TortoiseSVN) and have the checkout on a separate folder, commit some stuff to "trunk". Then use the Merge interface of TortoiseSVN at the "release" branch working copy, so you can easily "merge all from trunk" to your release branch, for example (or cherry-pick some revisions only). After the merge, you commit the changes at the release branch.

The only thing to really care about is that you "svn update" the release branch before the merge to avoid most of the conflicts that may arise (imagine some other people committing to the release branch, or just you doing it from other working copy, etc). You "update" the release branch before the merge, just as you "update" your trunk working copy to get the latest changes before doing some work.

Also be sure to check the manual of TortoiseSVN since there are some stuff to be considered about merges, but if you stick to TortoiseSVN it will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm on a locked system (running fedora) and do not have sudo access to even install Totuis SVN. Even if I could install it I can not use it... I am using pysvn package to invoke svn commands from a package management and version control system software that I working on as a developer. Would you be able to show how cherry_picking would work with commands alone (like an example)...? Also what is the significance of the svn switch would I need to use this as well for cherry picking?

Comment: Sorry but TortoiseSVN is a GUI app for Windows only, so as you say you're locked-in on command line. I recommend you to see the svnbook on merge then. Just remember modern svn DOES handle merges much better than is "recorded on old pages" of the internet. Meaning that it already remembers what is merged, etc. Hope that helps.